# <context:property-placeholder> properties not accessible to the child (web) context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

A typical use-case: I'm having `applicationContext.xml` and `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. In the parent context (`applicationContext.xml`) I have:

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

However, the properties loaded by it are not accessible to the web context - neither in xml, nor using `@Value`. (They are just not resolved and the expression (`${varName}`) is set as value instead)

I worked it around by adding the `<context:property-placeholder>` to `dispatcher-servlet.xml` as well, but I wondered whether:

1. This is expected behaviour
2. There isn't a better way to expose the properties to the child context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is an expected behaviour. `<context:property-placeholder>` creates a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which is applied at per-context basis. So, you'll need a postprocessor in the child context anyway.