# Why is the ${} variable not interpreted as a constructor-arg value, in my context file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a Spring 3.1 application, and I try to use a system variable in the context files. The variable "JAVA_MY_ENV" is defined on my System (on Windows, it is in the "System variables", from the control panel).

In web.xml, I can use it as a variable and it works, it is successfully replaced by the actual value of the variable (let's say "electrotype") :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener> 
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log/${JAVA_MY_ENV}.log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I can also use it in my main "bean" context, to do an import, and it also works :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- (...) -->

    <import resource="classpath:spring/app-config.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:spring/env/context-env-${JAVA_MY_ENV}.xml" />

</beans>
```

But In "app-config.xml", one of my other context file, I try this and it *doesn't* work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="appConfiguration" class="com.xxx.app.AppConfiguration">
        <constructor-arg value="${JAVA_MY_ENV}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The com.xxx.app.AppConfiguration receives the String "${JAVA_MY_ENV}" as the constructor parameter, not the interpreted value of it!

I'm not sure to understand where the ${} variables are interpreted and where they are not.

Is there a way I can pass the interpreted ${JAVA_MY_ENV} value to my com.xxx.app.AppConfiguration constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 3.0 in Spring you should be to inject values into properties

```
@Value("#{ systemProperties['JAVA_MY_ENV'] }") 
private String myVar;
```

or

```
<property name ="myVar" value="#{systemProperties['JAVA_MY_ENV']}"/>
```

Alternatively you can look into using the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer or similar class.  Creating this will tell spring how to look for variables.  Often i make a number of property files as well so that environment and internal property file values are available to the app.  e.g.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:someprops.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
  <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
  <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
```

A key element in the above example is the "searchSystemEnvironment" being set to true.  This tells spring to use env variables (which is what you want)

Comment: The problem is that I do not start my app with "-DJAVA_MY_ENV=electrotype" but I instead set JAVA_MY_ENV as a System global variable. In my app, System.getenv("JAVA_MY_ENV") returns "electrotype", but System.getProperty("JAVA_MY_ENV") returns NULL. @Value("#{ systemProperties['JAVA_MY_ENV'] }") is also NULL. I would prefere to be able to use the *exact same* ${JAVA_MY_ENV} variable that web.xml uses, to make sure the value is also the same! With a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, I wouldn't be sure if it's a "-D" var, or a global System property (If I use both one day, for some reason). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [<context:property-placeholder> properties not accessible to the child (web) context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816617/contextproperty-placeholder-properties-not-accessible-to-the-child-web-cont)
As I understand this is expected behavior. You should inject beans only in servlet context or to include configuration bean into servlet-context.xml

Answer (score 0):

To use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, suggested by BruceLowe, works. Another way (maybe more complicated) I found to resolve a *specific* property is using :

```
<bean id="JAVA_MY_ENV" class="org.springframework.util.SystemPropertyUtils" factory-method="resolvePlaceholders">
    <constructor-arg value="${JAVA_MY_ENV}" /> 
</bean>
```

This creates a **String** bean containing the *resolved* value of ${JAVA_MY_ENV}!

Then I can use this bean anywhere a bean ref can be used. For example as a constructor-arg:

```
<bean id="appConfiguration" class="com.xxx.app.AppConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg ref="JAVA_MY_ENV" />
</bean>
```

So now I use ${JAVA_MY_ENV} in places where it is interpreted, without adding PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, and the JAVA_MY_ENV bean otherwise.