# I can use properties in Spring servlet context, but not @Value annotation inside @Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, annotations

***-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:spring.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.path" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**com.my.path.MyController**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String myProperty;

    @RequestMapping("/my/path")
    public String default(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws Exception {

        // Any reference to myProperty above is null...

        return "view";
    }
}
```

I do have other beans defined by ID in my servlet context that use the same system property I'm trying to add to my controller via the Value annotation. I know they are present and with the right values. So I'm not sure why I just can't get the annotation to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing just about every tutorial I could for a day I realized this has to be some sort of classloader issue. So I reviewed my packaging structure, which is an EAR containing a WAR. Sure enough I had two spring bean jars of identical versions, one in EAR/lib and the other in WAR/WEB-INF/lib. Apparently the properties were picked up in the EAR, but the post processing was happening in the WAR (or something like that). So by sorting that out, and getting duplicate JARs out of the WAR it is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816617/contextproperty-placeholder-properties-not-accessible-to-the-child-web-cont). Do you happen to have more XML Spring contexts? Is the `component-scan` defined on the same Spring config as the `property-placeholder` as shown above?

Comment: The component scan and property placeholder are in the same servlet context.